# Multiple Dynamic Javascript Dropdowns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have currently got a 2-tier javascript drop down box attached to my form, and i am looking to add another 3-tiers, but completely seperate to my current javascript and can't unfortunately figure it out (quite new to javascript :(  )

Here what I have so far, it all works ( not even sure what framework to select on fiddle for it to display properly lol :( the embarassment haha

Any help is appreciated <3

Comment: If you want to do it that way why cant you just make another function similar to the one you currently have.

Comment: Every time I try to make a new function similar to my current the separate drop down refers to the latter one for some reason, complete brainfart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will probably be enough code for you to get the idea.

**[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/CEuZY/1/)**

I used jQuery to get handles to the various DOM elements. [Here is a quite decent resource](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) for browsing all jQuery selectors, events, effects, css, etc - despite the source. (Just keep hitting Next Chapter)

First, ***this*** is your code for catching the `optone` select element's **change** event, removed from inline javascript (which is never a good idea):

```
$('select[name=optone]').change(function() {
    var selval = $(this).val();
    setOptions(selval);
});
```

Simple enough, yes?

I left your first setOptions function as is, because it works. However, I wrote the next function `setOptions2()` in jQuery, to show you how much less typing is required.

To catch the next select element's change event:

```
$('select[name=opttwo]').change(function() {
    var sel2val = $(this).val();
    alert('You selected: ' + sel2val);
    setOptions2(sel2val);
    $('#selthreeDiv').show();
});
```

Notice [in my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CEuZY/1/) that I added a hidden div containing the 3rd select control, and I display that control when the 2nd select is changed...

Hopefully this will be of assistance.

Comment: I'm definitely going to take this into consideration for the future gibberish, seems like a better way of doing it overall to be honest

Comment: Thanks for the upvote and accept. Good luck on your project. You might also wish to review Alex Garret's excellent jQuery videos (FREE) at [thenewboston.com](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=32) and at [phpAcademy.org](http://phpacademy.org/). Once you get the hang of it (and memorize the w3schools cheat sheets I linked in the answer above), it will save you TONS of typing and browser-compatibility frustration.

Answer (score 0):

ok I did something like this and it worked for me.
your new javascript

```
 function setOptions2(chosen) {
        var selbox = document.myform.optthree;
        selbox.options.length = 0;
         if (chosen == "1") {
         selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Worked', ' ');

        }
        }
```

then added some new html

```
 <select name="opttwo" size="1" onchange="setOptions2(document.myform.optone.options[document.myform.optone.selectedIndex].value);" >
                <option value="Please Select Prompt Category" selected="selected">Please Select Prompt Category</option>
            </select>
            <select name="optthree" size="1">
                <option value="Please Select Prompt Category" selected="selected">Please Select Prompt Category</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: I actually changed it to setOptions2 rather than setOptions but forgot to define the function on the select lol :( totally burnt out, but really appreciate your help! cheers